# Converting ruby hash into c++ map

Tags: c++, ruby, hash, dictionary

Is there a way to convert a hash made in ruby to a C++ map? I've tried printing the hash into a file, but am unaware of how to read it into a C++ map.

The hash is printed in the following way:

```
stringA  =>  123 234 345 456 567
stringB  =>  12 54 103 313 567 2340 
...
```

The amount of numbers varies for each associated string, and the strings are unique. I would like to use:

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<unsigned int>> stringMap;
```

How can I read the string and array parts of each line separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use plain-Jane formatted input:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
std::string line;

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> v;

while (std::getline(infile, line)
{
  std::string key, sep;
  int n;

  std::istringstream iss(line);

  if (!(iss >> key >> sep)) { /* error */ }
  if (sep != "=>")          { /* error */ }

  while (iss >> n) v[key].push_back(n);

  // maybe check if you've reached the end of the line and error otherwise
  // or maybe add the option to end a line at a comment character
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the string contain spaces: `a string with spaces => 1 2 3`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's true. If you need that, replace the first input operation by a loop that waits for the `=>`, or use `substr()` to locate the separator. The OP is welcome to clarify whether this is required.

Comment: The string won't have any spaces, but could be a number valid as a string. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. A simple solution could look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("your_file.txt");
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<unsigned int>> stringMap;
    std::string key, dummy; // dummy is for eating the "=>"
    while(input >> key >> dummy) {
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(input), 
                  std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                  std::back_inserter(stringMap[key]));
        input.clear();
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- `stringMap[key]` will create a new entry in the map if none exists yet
- `std::istream_iterator<int>` will try to read integers from the file until an error happens (such as a character that cannot be converted to integer), or the end of the stream is reached
- `input.clear()` clears any errors from the stream (the `std::copy` above will always end in an error)
- **this solution will not work as expected if your keys can be parsed as integers, or if they contain spaces**

If these limitations are to strict for you, you could look into [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html).

Comment: This will fail if the strings contain spaces, it will also fail if numbers are valid as strings, like: `10 => 1 2 3 4 5`. "10" is a valid string, but also a valid number.